# Unable to install MYSQL using brew install mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am having problem on installing MYSQL using homebrew

My system info are as follows. Fresh Install of

MAC OSX 10.7.4
RUBY 1.9.3-p125
XCODE 4.3.3

when I issue the command > brew install mysql
I get the following errors

> DBSVR1:~ icareadmin$ brew install mysql
>   ==> Installing mysql dependency: cmake
>   ==> Downloading /downloads/project/machomebrew/Bottles/cmake-2.8.8.l
>
> ################################################################## 100.0%
>
> ==> Pouring cmake-2.8.8.lion.bottle.2.tar.gz /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/download_strategy.rb:118: warning:
>   conflicting chdir during another chdir block
>   /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.8: 653 files, 30M
>   ==> Installing mysql dependency: readline
>   ==> Downloading ftpmirror/readline/readline-6.2.tar.gz
>                                                                              0.0% curl: (52) Empty reply from server Trying a mirror...
>   ==> Downloading ftp/gnu/readline/readline-6.2.tar.gz
>
> ################################################################## 100.0%
>
> ==> Downloading patches
>                                                                              0.0% curl: (52) Empty reply from server
>                                                                              0.0% curl: (52) Empty reply from server
>                                                                              0.0% curl: (52) Empty reply from server
>                                                                              0.0% curl: (52) Empty reply from server Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/curl -qf#LA Homebrew\ 0.9.2\ (Ruby\ 1.8.7-357;\
>   Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.7.4)
>   ftpmirror/readline/readline-6.2-patches/readline62-001 -o
>   000-homebrew.diff
>   ftpmirror.gnu.org/readline/readline-6.2-patches/readline62-002 -o
>   001-homebrew.diff
>   ftpmirror.gnu.org/readline/readline-6.2-patches/readline62-003 -o
>   002-homebrew.diff
>   ftpmirror.gnu.org/readline/readline-6.2-patches/readline62-004 -o
>   003-homebrew.diff

NOTE: I have omitted all the hyperlinks on my error since i am a new user here and I cannot post multiple hyperlinks.

As you can see i am getting something like this

curl: (52) Empty reply from server

when brew is trying to download readline-6.2.tar.gz from the ftpmirror.

is it possible for me to download manually those patches and let brew to recognize it when I install it again? If yes, where should I put all those files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure Homebrew is at its lates by running `brew update`

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee thanks but this is a fresh install, and I have followed the turorial that worked for me before.

Comment: You could also try `brew install readline` first

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee same error sir, it seems brew cannot connect to ftp.gnu.org server.

Comment: @jwg2s Thanks, but I did run brew doctor and yes its ready to brew.

Comment: I am wondering about this line  /usr/bin/curl -qf#LA Homebrew\ 0.9.2\ (Ruby\ 1.8.7-357) since I am using Ruby version 1.9.3-p125, is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my further reading on the issue, found out that this is not mysql issue. It is somewhere on the installation / downloading part of readline from ftp.gnu.org

found myself a solution by changing link from the readline formula under /usr/local/Library/Formula/ with a working link (cannot post link, me so newbie here). After finding out the solution, this work around was backed up on this [link](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13459). As far as I know this is still a painful issue on readline brew.

HTH.